# How to explain or name 'uniform' density over a certain coordinate system?

Tags: probability-distributions, random

I'm having trouble putting words on a concept.
I'm comparing some Monte-Carlo data with uniformly random distributed data.
The random data is not uniform in a normal rectangular coordinate system, but it is uniform over pseudorapidity.

Pseudorapidity is a coordinate system used in accelerator physics, described  as follows.

$$\eta = -\ln(\tan(\frac{\theta}{2}))$$ where $$0 \lt \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$$

I used the inverse cdf sampling function to create random samples that fit this function. No biggie. But I don't know how to describe the resulting data to my colleagues. I've settled for now on "random samples of uniform density over pseudorapidity", but it leaves a weird taste in my mouth.

Does anyone know anything better to call it?

Answer (score 1):

For $\theta\in(0,\pi/2]$ we have $\eta\in[0,\infty),$ so the distribution of $\eta$ *cannot be uniform*. ([There exists no uniform distribution over an unbounded interval.](https://www.quora.com/Why-is-there-no-continuous-uniform-probability-distribution-over-an-unbounded-interval)) Thus, the phrase "uniform over pseudorapidity" is nonsensical in this context. If you sampled angles $\theta_i$ uniformly at random over $(0,\pi/2]$ and simply computed the corresponding $\eta_i = -\ln(\tan(\frac{\theta_i}{2}))$, then these $\eta_i$ would constitute a (non-uniform) random sample of pseudorapidities induced by that uniform distribution of angles.

Comment: This is technically correct. Perhaps I should have stronger constraints on the angles.

Comment: @user55924 Yes -- if $\eta$ is uniformly distributed on a finite interval, then $\theta$ is *non*uniformly distributed on an interval bounded away from zero. To simulate a random sample $(\eta_i)_{i=1..n}$ from such a uniform distribution on, say, $[\eta_{lo},\eta_{hi}]$, we only need to compute $\eta_i=\eta_{lo}+(\eta_{hi}-\eta_{lo})u_i,$ where the $u_i$ are pseudorandom numbers (e.g. from `random()` in software). You mention "inverse cdf sampling", but nothing like that needs to be involved.